# Build and run an Eclipse project manually

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I'm doing a Java Project in Eclipse and I wanted to know how to compile these files manually. Right now, Eclipse does the building and running part and I would like to do it manually as we have to submit only the .java files. Now, I know that we have to use the `javac` and `java` command but these are throwing up exceptions from Java. So, here is what I have:

Assume the Eclipse project is named as Prj1. So the root directory is Prj1. This has 4 folders, `.settings`, `bin`, `doc` and `src`. There are also 3 files named `.classpath`, `.project` and `javadoc.xml`. I also have a text file `a.txt` in this root folder which is read by my java program (not as an input but somewhere in the middle of the execution, the file is opened and its contents are read). The `src` folder has 5 class files in a package. That is, the `src` folder has one folder called `package1` and inside this, there are 5 class files.

So, how should I build this from the terminal with the `javac` command and in which folder should I be? Also, where will the bin files be generated and where should I place the `a.txt` text file which is read during run-time? I am unable to do it on my own. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you should be "in" the `src` folder and compile it with:

```
javac -d ../bin package1/*.java
```

The `-d` argument specifies the *root* output directory for classes - the compiler will create a directory hierarchy based on the packages in the source files.

Comment: And where should the text file be placed?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) as a build tool. The [m2e plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) provides easy eclipse integration. You can then create a new maven project from eclipse or create it from the command line and import it as a maven project into your eclipse workspace.

Maven will also make your dependency management more easy.

There are of course alternative build tools, like [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/)

UPDATE:
regarding the text file: you can treat it as a classpath resource. In eclipse it resides in a source folder. Name it 'resources' for example. From your code refer to it like

```
InputStream stream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/a.txt");
```

On the command line just copy the text file into the bin folder.

Comment: But my instructor will do it manually without using any tools. And he requires that the file be able to build without external tools.

Comment: Ok, then John's answer is the way to go.

Comment: If that requirement wasn't there, I might as well have used Eclipse to build it :P

Comment: In many applications the build might include much more than a simple eclipse java project can provide. Or the application might be built on a continuous integration server where there is no eclipse instance present and some command line scripting is needed.

Comment: Another reason for not wanting to rely on eclipse as a build tool is when you share a project with other developers who might use a different IDE like Netbeans or IntelliJ.

Comment: Also, where to put the text file?